# Posts by tag - Creating a reset

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a rather neat filter tag that will narrow down results in a specific post category to just the posts within that category that have the selected tag.

I am struggling to get the stock 'select tag...' option to reset the filter and show all results again - so once a user selects a tag the only way to reset the list is by refresh.

Here is my filter within the function.php script:

```
// CASE STUDY FILTER 
function my_filters(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => $_POST['date']
    );

    if( isset( $_POST['tagfilter'] ) ):
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['tagfilter']
            )
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( $query->have_posts() ):

            while( $query->have_posts() ):
                $query->the_post();

                echo "<article class=\"post-box " . get_post_class() . "\">";

                    echo "<a href=\"" . get_the_permalink() . "\" class=\"box-link\"></a>";

                    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );

                    echo "<div class=\"cs-image\" style=\"background-image: url('" . $url . "')\"></div>";

                    $case_study = get_field('case_study_page_content');

                    if( $case_study ):

                        echo "<div class=\"cs-text-container\">";

                            while( have_rows('case_study_page_content') ): the_row();
                                $case_study_title = get_sub_field('title');
                                $case_study_author = get_sub_field('author');

                                echo "<h2>" . $case_study_title . "</h2>";

                                echo "<p>" . $case_study_author . "</p>";
                            endwhile;

                        echo "</div>";

                    endif;

                echo "</article>";


            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();

        else :

            echo 'No case studies found';

        endif;

    die();

    endif;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_customfilter', 'my_filters');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_customfilter', 'my_filters');
// END CASE STUDY FILTER
```

The form that this takes input from is here:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="advanced-filterform">
    <?php
        if( $terms = get_terms( 'post_tag', 'orderby=name' ) ) :
            echo '<select class="tagfilter" name="tagfilter"><option>Select tag...</option>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
        endforeach;
            echo '</select>';
        endif;
    ?>

    <button>Apply filters</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="customfilter">
</form>
```

As simply as possible without creating a tag on every post - how can I implement this.